# Is it possible to make an `any Protocol` conform to Codable?

Tags: swift, codable, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a `Codable` struct with an `[any Protocol]` in Swift 5.7

```
struct Account: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var wallets: [any Wallet]
}

protocol Wallet: Codable {
    var id: String { get set }
    //... other codable properties
}
```

However, I'm getting these errors even though `Wallet` conforms to `Codable`

> Type 'Account' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

> Type 'Account' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Is it possible to make an `any` conform to `Codable`?

or is this still not possible with Swift 5.7?

**EDIT**: *As answered, you have to implement your own conformance. This is how I did mine:*

```
protocol Wallet: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: String { get set }
}

struct DigitalWallet: Wallet {
    var id: String
    // other properties
}

struct CashWallet: Wallet {
    var id: String
    // other properties
}

struct Account {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var wallets: [any Wallet]
}

extension Account: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case digitalWallet
        case cashWallet
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)

        let dW = try values.decode([DigitalWallet].self, forKey: .digitalWallet)
        let cW = try values.decode([CashWallet].self, forKey: .cashWallet)
        wallets = []
        wallets.append(contentsOf: dW)
        wallets.append(contentsOf: cW)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

        var digitalWallet: [DigitalWallet] = []
        var cashWallet: [CashWallet] = []

        wallets.forEach { wallet in
            if wallet is DigitalWallet {
                digitalWallet.append(wallet as! DigitalWallet)
            } else if wallet is CashWallet {
                cashWallet.append(wallet as! CashWallet)
            }
        }
        try container.encode(digitalWallet, forKey: .digitalWallet)
        try container.encode(cashWallet, forKey: .cashWallet)
    }
}
```

But I have reverted to just using this instead:

```
struct Account: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var cashWallets: [CashWallet]
    var digitalWallets: [DigitalWallet]
}
```

I worry the performance overhead of `any Protocol` isn't worth it just to comply to the Dependency Inversion Principle.

Comment: Encodes do: yes (if I’m not mistaken). Decidable: no. How would it know which of the wallet types to decode a piece of data into?

Comment: this is actually what I realized later, haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protocols do not conform to themselves, so `any Wallet` is not itself Codable, and so you won't get an automatic conformance here, and you won't get automatic handling of arrays. But you can handle it yourself without trouble:

```
extension Account: Encodable {
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case wallets
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)

        var walletContainer = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .wallets)
        for wallet in wallets {
            try walletContainer.encode(wallet)
        }
    }
}
```

If you comment-out `wallets` temporarily, Xcode 14 will auto-complete the rest of the `encode(to:)` method for you, so you only need to write the loop for `wallets`.

This is something that may improve in the future. There's no deep reason that Swift can't auto-generate this conformance. It just doesn't today.

However, as Alexander notes, it is not in possible to conform to Decodable in a general way because it requires an `init`. You have to know which type you want to decode, and the serialized data doesn't include that information (at least the way you've described it). So you'll have to make choices that you hand-write (for example, using some default Wallet type).

Comment: "so `any Wallet` is not itself Codable" Boy, I'm *so* happy about the `any` keyword. It's simple addition to this sentence makes it so much easier to distinguish the `Wallet` protocol from `Wallet` existentials!