# How do I get automatic Encodable conformance with array property but without using generics?

Tags: swift, generics, existential-type, swift5.7

I would like to define a struct with automatic conformance to Encodable, where the struct has an array of Encodable elements:

```
struct EncodableBagB: Encodable {
  var values: [Encodable] // ❌ Type 'EncodableBagB' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
}
```

If we take a step back and not use an array, the way to solve this is to move Encodable to be a generic:

```
struct EncodableBagA1<T: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var value: T //  Okay, but doesn't work for arrays
}
```

If I do the same with an array, I lose the ability to store heterogenous elements:

```
struct EncodableBagB1<T: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var values: [T]
}
EncodableBagB1(values: ["A", "B"])
EncodableBagB1(values: ["A", "B", 1]) // ❌ Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

The only workaround seems to be to introduce a ton of duplicate generic structures:

```
struct EncodableBagB1_2<T0: Encodable, T1: Encodable, T2: Encodable, T3: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var value0: T0
  var value1: T1
  var value2: T2
  var value3: T3

  init(_ encodable0: T0, _ encodable1: T1, _ encodable2: T2, _ encodable3: T3) {
    value0 = encodable0
    value1 = encodable1
    value2 = encodable2
    value3 = encodable3
  }
  //  Okay, but very verbose and requires a bunch of duplicate structures (e.g. T0, T0-1, T0-2, T0-3, etc.) for each permutation
}
```

Can Swift 5.7's `some` or `any` keywords help in this situation, or are there any upcoming proposals which would eventually address this problem? What is this problem called (so I know what to look for in the future)?

I'd prefer to avoid manual type erasure (e.g. `AnyEncodable`) if possible, since I'd like to use `Mirror` on the items within the array.

Note: I'm using `Encodable` to simplify the example. The actual protocol I'm eventually using looks more like this: `protocol Foo: Encodable { func bar() }`.

---

Here is an exhaustive list of everything I tried:

```
// MARK: Single value

struct EncodableBagA: Encodable {
  var value: Encodable // ❌ Type 'EncodableBagA' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
}

struct EncodableBagA1<T: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var value: T //  Okay, but doesn't work for arrays
}

struct EncodableBagA2: Encodable { // ❌ Type 'EncodableBagA2' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
  var value: any Encodable
}

struct EncodableBagA3: Encodable {
  var value: some Encodable // ❌ Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type
}

// MARK: Array

struct EncodableBagB: Encodable { // ❌ Type 'EncodableBagB' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
  var values: [any Encodable]
}

struct EncodableBagB1<T: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var values: [T]
}
EncodableBagB1(values: ["A", "B"])
EncodableBagB1(values: ["A", "B", 1]) // ❌ Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

struct EncodableBagB2<T: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var values: [any T] // ❌ 'any' has no effect on type parameter 'T'
}

struct EncodableBagB3<T: Encodable>: Encodable { // ❌ Type 'EncodableBagB3' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'
  var values: [some T] // ❌ An 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class
}

struct EncodableBagB1_1<T0: Encodable, T1: Encodable, T2: Encodable, T3: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var value0: T0
  var value1: T1
  var value2: T2
  var value3: T3

  init(_ encodables: Encodable...) {
    value0 = encodables[0] // ❌ Cannot assign value of type 'any Encodable' to type 'T0'
    value1 = encodables[1] // ❌ Cannot assign value of type 'any Encodable' to type 'T1'
    value2 = encodables[2] // ❌ Cannot assign value of type 'any Encodable' to type 'T2'
    value3 = encodables[3] // ❌ Cannot assign value of type 'any Encodable' to type 'T3'
  }
}

struct EncodableBagB1_2<T0: Encodable, T1: Encodable, T2: Encodable, T3: Encodable>: Encodable {
  var value0: T0
  var value1: T1
  var value2: T2
  var value3: T3

  init(_ encodable0: T0, _ encodable1: T1, _ encodable2: T2, _ encodable3: T3) {
    value0 = encodable0
    value1 = encodable1
    value2 = encodable2
    value3 = encodable3
  }
  //  Okay, but very verbose and requires a bunch of duplicate structures (e.g. T0, T0-1, T0-2, T0-3, etc.) for each permutation
}
```

Comment: You cannot have *automatic* conformance for this case. The Swift compiler will not generate an automatic conformance. It's not a fundamental problem of the language; the compiler just doesn't have this feature currently. I believe this question is a close duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123640/is-it-possible-to-make-an-any-protocol-conform-to-codable/73124904#73124904 and the answer there applies. Let me know if you believe there is more to this question, and I can reopen this.

Comment: That explains it, thanks. Since there is no way to do what I wanted, I ended up using the `AnyEncodable` type eraser strategy, but made sure it has a `wrapped: Encodable` property so that `Mirror` finds all the properties on the original type too.

Comment: Consider implementing CustomReflectable in that case. You can return the wrapped value's mirror as the mirror transparently.