# How to express "Any Encodable" in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to express "Any Encodable" in Swift.

In Java, you can use the name of an interface as a type in any context. In Swift when I try to do this, I get errors such as "Type 'any Encodable' cannot conform to 'Encodable'".

I think I'm just missing something simple here as I'm sure it's possible to do what I want.

Thanks

Comment: The typical solution is to use a [generic](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics). E.g. `func foo<T: Encodable>(_ value: T) {…}`. It is a very common pattern that you will undoubtedly find elsewhere on S.O. or the web if you look for functions that encode objects.

Comment: The [`encode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/2895034-encode) function, itself, employs generics and you can follow the same pattern in your code.

Comment: Can you show the actual code where you got the  "Type 'any Encodable' cannot conform to 'Encodable'" error? While I can probably *guess* what you are doing, the question is much easier to answer if you can show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This used to be tricky in Swift, but since around 5.7 it's just `any Encodable`:

```
struct S {
    var e: any Encodable
}

let s = S(e: 1)
```

That does not mean that you can pass `any Encodable` to something that requires `Encodable`. That hasn't changed. [Protocols do not conform to themselves.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123640/is-it-possible-to-make-an-any-protocol-conform-to-codable/73124904#73124904) As noted in the comments, generally for Encodable this isn't a problem. You can, and should, use generics rather than create an existential wrapper. The `any` keyword is often a hint that there's a better solution in Swift, though there are times it's necessary.